# add / remove seed scylladb from container create by docker run

Tags: docker, scylla

How to add or remove seed from node scylladb that create with docker run, for example :

```
docker run -d scylladb/scylla:4.5.2 \
--authenticator PasswordAuthenticator \
--authorizer CassandraAuthorizer \
--seeds SCYLLA-N1, SCYLLA-N2
```

After container succes create and work well - And i wanto to add SCYLLA-N3 as seed or i want remove SCYLLA-N1 from seeds.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running docker (no K8s), all parameters that you use when spinning up your container are saved under `/etc/scylla.d/docker.conf`.

You can edit this file and then use `supervisorctl restart scylla` to update the seed list as well as other parameters you wish.

Comment: Thanks @felipe. i will try your sollutions